# How to convert to tuples and enhance performance of SQL requests of 1 row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to do it?

```
  val (a,b) = spark.sql("SELECT 1,2").first
```

### Notes and motivations

I need to code-review a code that has a lot of isolated attributions from SQL, example:

```scala
val today = spark.sql("SELECT date_format(now(),'yyyyMMdd')").as[String].first
val yesterday = spark.sql("SELECT date_format(date_add(now(),-1),'yyyyMMdd')").as[String].first
val xMax= spark.sql("SELECT max(x) FROM h_db.tt").as[String].first.toInt
val xMin= spark.sql("SELECT min(x) FROM h_db.tt").as[String].first.toInt
```

... And try something as

```scala
val (today,yesterday) = spark.sql("""
  SELECT date_format(now(),'yyyyMMdd'),  date_format(date_add(now(),-1),'yyyyMMdd')
""").as[(String,String)]
// error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type

val (xMax,xMIn) = spark.sql("SELECT max(x), min(x) FROM h_db.tt") // ... same problem
```

The SQL command SELECT returns a tuple, so theoretically tuples are the natural choice, with minimal casts and some syntax elegance. The main motivation, anyway, is performance: to recuce the number of SQL  SELECTs.

Comment: Doesn't `val (a,b) = spark.sql("SELECT 1,2").as[(Int, Int)].first` works?  Remember that a **Dataframe** is a **Dataset[Row]** thus, `first` is a **Row**. But you can always as Spark to do the cast from **Row** to whatever you know there is in there _(in this case a tuple)_ before asking for the `first`.

Comment: Hi @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, yes! ... Lets I delete the question? Or you prefer to post a complete answer?

Comment: I am too lazy to do that :p If you want to redact a complete answer I will be happy to up-vote it, I believe that as simple as this may seems, it could be a common problem that deserves to be documented. Maybe even rephrase the question to something like `How to get a T from a DataFrame of one row in Apache Spark`.

Comment: The result of `spark.sql("SELECT 1,2").first` is Row, and the `spark.sql("SELECT 1,2").first.schema`  is **StructType**... So it is a typical problem of "how to cast?"

Comment: I would believe so, I haven't touched **Spark** seriously in almost two years now. I remember the `as` method because I really liked it, and I supposed that using it before the `first` should work.

Answer (score 1):

(this is a Wiki, please enhance the answer with good English and more didactic explanations)

---

Based on @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez,

Is possible to do something as `val (a,b) = spark.sql("SELECT 1,2").first`, the correct cast and syntax is:

```scala
val (a,b) = spark.sql("SELECT 1,2").as[(Int, Int)].first
```

### Explanations

Is possible to [introspect the datatypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) by [Spark-shell](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) results and checking schemas:

- The result of `spark.sql("SELECT 1,2").first` is `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`, that is, is Row.
- The schema is `spark.sql("SELECT 1,2").first.schema`, a StructType: `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType`  = `StructType(StructField(1,IntegerType,false), StructField(2,IntegerType,false))`

so, after checked datatypes you can decide what to do, or understand your real casting problem.

Remember that a Dataframe is a Dataset[Row] thus, `.first` is a Row. But you can always use Spark `as[T]` to do the cast from Row to whatever you know there is in there (in this case a tuple) before asking for the first.

Other curious things, (please edit a didactic explianation here!):

- To cast before or after the `.first`? Why?
- Cast using `toTypeX` or `as[TypeX]`?  All the same?
- There are some "implicit cast"?
- ...

### Real life examples

Using the examples of the question and enhancing it:

```scala
val (isoToday,isoYesterday) = spark.sql("""
  SELECT date_format(now(),'yy-yy-MMdd'),  date_format(date_add(now(),-1),'yyyy-MM-dd')
""").as[(String,String)].first

val (today,yesterday) = spark.sql("""
  SELECT date_format(now(),'yyyyMMdd'),  date_format(date_add(now(),-1),'yyyyMMdd')
""").as[(String,String)].first  // as[(Int,Int)] not works...

val (intToday,intYesterday) = (today.toInt,yesterday.toInt) // no direct transform?

val (xMax,xMIn) = spark.sql("SELECT max(x), min(x) FROM h_db.tt").as[(Int,Int)].first  
   // direct to int, because SQL is typed
```